# How to add an upload field on a laravel backpack relationship field?

Tags: mysql, eloquent, laravel-blade, laravel-9, laravel-backpack

I have created an Invoice Crud Controller with multiple relationships like Products, Services, Trips and Expenses. All data is working fine except for the image field of Expenses. For us to invoice an expense we would require to upload a picture with the receipt.

So I have created the model **InvoicesExpense.php** and define the relationship with the **Invoice.php** model. I also created the function for the event to set the path of the uploaded file **setInvoicesExpensePictureAttribute()**.

**InvoicesExpense.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class InvoicesExpense extends Model
{
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Models\Traits\CrudTrait;
    use \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

    /**
     * Indicates if the model should be timestamped.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $table        =   'invoices_expenses';
    protected $primaryKey   =   'invoices_expense_id';
    public $timestamps = false;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'invoice_id',
        'invoices_expense_name',
        'invoices_expense_description',
        'invoices_expense_price',
        'invoices_expense_quantity',
        'invoices_expense_total',
        'invoices_expense_picture',
        'invoices_expense_created',
        'invoices_expense_updated',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'id' => 'integer',
        'invoice_id' => 'integer',
        'invoices_expense_price' => 'float',
        'invoices_expense_quantity' => 'float',
        'invoices_expense_total' => 'float',
        'invoices_expense_created' => 'datetime',
        'invoices_expense_updated' => 'timestamp',
    ];

    protected $appends = [
        'invoices_expense_total',
        'invoices_expense_picture'
    ];

    public function invoice() {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\Models\Invoice::class, 'invoice_id');
    }

    public function setInvoicesExpenseTotalAttribute($value) {
        $this->attributes['invoices_expense_total'] = $this->attributes['invoices_expense_price']*$this->attributes['invoices_expense_quantity'];
    }

    public function setInvoicesExpensePictureAttribute($value)
    {
        $attribute_name = 'invoices_expense_picture';
        // or use your own disk, defined in config/filesystems.php
        $disk = config('backpack.base.root_disk_name');
        // destination path relative to the disk above
        $destination_path = "public/uploads/invoices/expenses";



        // if the image was erased
        if (empty($value)) {
            // delete the image from disk
            if (isset($this->{$attribute_name}) && !empty($this->{$attribute_name})) {
                \Storage::disk($disk)->delete($this->{$attribute_name});
            }
            // set null on database column
            return $this->attributes[$attribute_name] = null;
        }

        // if a base64 was sent, store it in the db
        if (Str::startsWith($value, 'data:image'))
        {
            // 0. Make the image
            $image = \Image::make($value)->encode('jpg', 90);

            // 1. Generate a filename.
            $filename = md5($value.time()).'.jpg';
            //$filename = strtolower(Str::replace(' ', '_', $this->attributes['supplier_name'])) .'_logo.jpg';

            // 2. Store the image on disk.
            \Storage::disk($disk)->put($destination_path.'/'.$filename, $image->stream());

            // 3. Delete the previous image, if there was one.
            if (isset($this->{$attribute_name}) && !empty($this->{$attribute_name})) {
                \Storage::disk($disk)->delete($this->{$attribute_name});
            }

            // 4. Save the public path to the database
            // but first, remove "public/" from the path, since we're pointing to it
            // from the root folder; that way, what gets saved in the db
            // is the public URL (everything that comes after the domain name)
            $public_destination_path = Str::replaceFirst('public/', '', $destination_path);
            return $this->attributes[$attribute_name] = $public_destination_path.'/'.$filename;
        } elseif (!empty($value)) {
            // if value isn't empty, but it's not an image, assume it's the model value for that attribute.
            return $this->attributes[$attribute_name] = $this->{$attribute_name};
        }
    }

    public static function boot() {
        parent::boot();

        static::creating(static function($model) {
            $model->invoices_expense_total = '0.00';
            $model->invoices_expense_picture = '0.00';
        });
    }
}
```

In the **Invoice.php** model I have created the relationship between Invoice and InvoiceExpense.

**Invoice.php**

```
public function invoices_expenses() {
        return $this->hasMany(\App\Models\InvoicesExpense::class, 'invoice_id');
    }
```

In the controller **InvoiceCrudController.php** i have added the necessary column.

**InvoiceCrudController.php**

```
 CRUD::addField([
            'name'  =>  'invoices_expenses',
            'label' =>  'Expenses',
            'type' => 'relationship',
            'new_item_label' => 'Add Expense',
            'tab' => 'Expenses',
            'subfields' => [
                [
                    'name'          => 'invoices_expense_name',
                    'label'         => 'Expense name',
                    'type'          => 'text',
                    'wrapper'   =>  [ 'class' => 'form-group col-sm-2' ]
                ],
                [
                    'name'          => 'invoices_expense_description',
                    'label'         => 'Description',
                    'type'          => 'text',
                    'wrapper'   =>  [ 'class' => 'form-group col-sm-4' ]
                ],
                [
                    'name'          =>  'invoices_expense_price',
                    'type'          =>  'number',
                    'label'         =>  'Price',
                    'default'       =>  '0.00',
                    'prefix'        =>  '&pound;',
                    'attributes'    =>  ["step" => "any"],
                    'wrapper'       =>  [ 'class' => 'form-group col-sm-2' ]
                ],
                [
                    'name'          =>  'invoices_expense_quantity',
                    'type'          =>  'number',
                    'label'         =>  'Quantity',
                    'default'       =>  '1',
                    'attributes'    =>  ["step" => "any"],
                    'wrapper'       =>  [ 'class' => 'form-group col-sm-2' ]
                ],
                [
                    'name'          =>  'invoices_expense_picture',
                    'label'         =>  'Picture',
                    'type'          =>  'upload',
                    'upload'        =>  true,
                    'crop'          =>  true,
                    'wrapper'       =>  [ 'class' => 'form-group col-sm-2' ]
                ]
            ]
        ]);
```

I have also created the database table **invoices_expenses**
[image]

I have created the following rule in **InvoiceRequest.php**

```
'invoices_expenses.*.invoices_expense_name'         =>  'required',
            'invoices_expenses.*.invoices_expense_description'  =>  'nullable',
            'invoices_expenses.*.invoices_expense_price'        =>  'string|required',
            'invoices_expenses.*.invoices_expense_quantity'     =>  'required',
            'invoices_expenses.*.invoices_expense_total'     =>  'nullable',
            'invoices_expenses.*.invoices_expense_picture'      =>  'required'
```

I can select a picture, and i can create the record, but after creating, my picture column in the database is NULL
[image]

Could you guys please assist me?

Thank you,
George